# Using '<' or '>' operator with if statement in Repeater

Tags: html, asp.net, if-statement

I want to use if state in a repeater like that;

```
<%#Eval("FN").ToString().Count > 0 ? "SB" : "" %>
```

it returns me `error 73` that it cannot be used with `>` operator.

How can set it for if FN is empty it shows nothing or it has something it shows SB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `!= null` or  `isEmpty()` depending on what you actually would get for FN

Answer (score 0):

maybe protected func works for you

ASP

```
<%= validate(Eval("FN")) %>
```

C#

```
protected Func<object, string> validate = fn => fn.ToString().Count > 0 ? "SB" : "";
```

Comment: It can be work altough I did not want to work in codebehind just for this simple thing. Just seen a bit clean.
Thanks ;)